# Close MatDialog upon successful login

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I want upon a succesful login to close my MatDialog, I'm using AWS Amplify UI components for the login/register functionality and those are placed in a simple MatDialog. Here is simplified version of my code of a navbar component:

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

in ngOnInit I'm subscribed to authService like this

```
    this.authService.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(isLogged => {
      if(isLogged){
        this.isLoggedIn = true
        this.closeDialog() // and here I've tried countless things, this.dialog.closeAll(), getting the dialogRef and just using the close() method but nothing works, and I've checked I enter in the condition when I login
      }
    })
```

and outside ngOnInit I have those two methods

```
  openDialog(): void{
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }
  closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.getDialogById(this.dialogRef['id']).close() // and again here I tried closeAll() still didnt work 
  }
```

but still upon a successful login the AWS Amplify UI login component disappear and I'm just left with an empty div with a transparent black background.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing the closeDialog function

```
import {MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';

constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>)

closeDialog(): void {this.dialogRef.close();}
```

Comment: I'm getting ```R3InjectorError(AppModule)[MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef -> MatDialogRef]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!``` when initializing the dialogRef in the constructor

Comment: Fixed the error but still the dialog doesn't close